# Delecting empty ModelChoiceField in template

Tags: python, django

Hi have the following form field.

**forms.py**

```
self.fields['sender_name'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=this_originator_name)
```

In my template I would like to detect if the select has no values (queryset is empty) to display a message and link.

This is what I have tried, but with no success...

**template...**

```
{% if form.content.value == ""  %}

link here

{% endif %}
```

PS I'm not looking for  `empty_label`. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
{% if form.sender_name.queryset.count == 0 %}

link here

{% endif %}
```

Note: I can't remember exactly, but it may actually be `form.sender_name.field.queryset.count`